# Google Sheets Conditional Formatting, set one cell as true if to other cells are true

Tags: google-sheets

I have three columns.

G is if the product has a women's picture.
H is if the product has a unisex product.
S is if we need to send that product on a photoshoot.

I want to make a condition that says that the S-column should mark the checkbox as "true" if the checkbox inside H and G is not marked as true.

Meaning that if we do not have a unisex or a womens picture on one product, it has to be sent on a photoshoot.

Anyone knows how I can do this?

Comment: Welcome! What if both checkboxes are unchecked? There are several options for formulas: `=(G2+H2)=1` if there is only one (any) flag, `=(G2+H2)<2` if at least one (or both flags) is missing

Comment: Thank you! Here's another solution I got https://support.google.com/docs/thread/174852592?hl=en